# Zend Navigation Custom Rendering

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

I'm trying to create a custom navigation for zend navigation but i have two questions:

1. How do i pass variables to custom partial phtml, or if it's possible?
2. How do i set a class trough the whole active menu tree?

This is my code so far:

in the controller:

```
$config = new Zend_Config($menu);
$nav = new Zend_Navigation();
$nav->addPages($config);
$this->view->nav = $nav;
```

in the view:

```
<?php echo $this->navigation($this->nav)->menu()->setPartial('menu.phtml')->render(); ?>
```

and my partial:

```
<?php

function genMenu($container)
{
    foreach ($container as $page)
    {
        echo '<li>';

        $href = $page->uri;
        $target = '_self';

        echo '<a href="' . $href . '" target="' . $target . '">' . $page->label . '</a>';

        if (!empty($page->pages))
        {
            echo '<ul>';

            genMenu($page->pages);

            echo '</ul>';
        }

        echo '</li>';
    }
}

echo '<ul>';

genMenu($this->container);

echo '</ul>';
```

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 4):

```
echo $this->navigation($this->nav)->menu()->setPartial('menu.phtml')->render(); ?>
```

is not quite correct, you have the right idea but try

```
//This will pass a valid container to your partial with the $this->nav
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderPartial($this->nav,'menu.phtml') ?>
```

here is the api:

```
public function renderPartial(Zend_Navigation_Container $container = null,
                                  $partial = null)
```

also this bit looks a little wonky as well:

```
$config = new Zend_Config($menu);
$nav = new Zend_Navigation();
$nav->addPages($config);
$this->view->nav = $nav;
```

I don't think ->addPages() is what you want here, I think what you need is:

```
//where $menu is the container and is config(.ini) object not .xml
//for xml use Zend_Config_Xml or Zend_Config_Json for JSON
$config = new Zend_Config($menu);
$nav = new Zend_Navigation($config);
//assign the container to the view
$this->view->nav = $nav;
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction on my code, i'm kind of new on zend atm! Still, i got the same doubts.. how to pass vars to my partial, and how to know the active tree.. that will help me a lot on my partial builder :\

Comment: @MGP anytime you call a partial or partiaLoop to be rendered one of the things the constructor requires is a model (read array() or object()) of some kind. renderPartial() is no exception, the first argument is the model, in this case a Zend_Navigation_Container object.

Comment: and what about get the active tree, e.g., to add a particular class to all the links in that tree (or breadcrumb) to the last child?

Comment: @MGP you just went over my head, sorry

Answer (score 2):

See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4338969/470601)

Add this line to valid ACL if use ACL

```
if ($this->navigation()->accept($page))
```

Its result

```
...    
    foreach ( $iterator as $page ) {
        //VALID ACL
        if ($this->navigation()->accept($page)) {
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
    ..
```